# PyQt5 Desktop Application (I converted it using pyinstaller) won't run when renamed

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, ordinal

So I made a CRUD system using `PyQt5`.
I then coverted it to .exe using `PyInstaller`.

Now the problem is I wanted to rename it. But when I do, it now won't run. It also won't run when pasted to the desktop.  What should I do?

The error by the way is

```
The ordinal 380 could not be located in the dynamic link library
```